# Retries and advices in spring integration

Tags: spring-integration

I've created a simple example to learn about retries and advices. Here is the sample configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@ComponentScan
public class SimpleConfiguration2 {
  @Bean
  public DirectChannel requestChannel() {
   return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public DirectChannel aChannel() {
   return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public DirectChannel retryLaterChannel() {
   return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public DirectChannel tapChannel() {
   return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public DirectChannel endChannel() {
   return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public ExceptionThrowingTransformer exceptionThrowingTransformer() {
    return new ExceptionThrowingTransformer();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow initFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(requestChannel())
                           .gateway(aChannel(), e -> e.advice(retryAdvice())
                                                      .errorChannel(retryLaterChannel()))
                           .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public Advice retryAdvice() {
    final RequestHandlerRetryAdvice advice = new RequestHandlerRetryAdvice();
    advice.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate());
    return advice;
  }

  @Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryTemplate() {
    final RetryTemplate ret = new RetryTemplate();
    ret.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy());
    ret.setThrowLastExceptionOnExhausted(false);
    return ret;
  }

  @Bean
  public RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
    final Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> map = new HashMap<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>() {{
        put(RuntimeException.class, true);
      }
      private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
    };
    final RetryPolicy ret = new SimpleRetryPolicy(3, map, true);
    return ret;
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow aChannelFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(aChannel())
                           .transform("C: "::concat)
                           .transform(exceptionThrowingTransformer())
                           .channel(endChannel())
                           .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow endFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(endChannel())
                           .handle(String.class, (p, h) -> p)
                           .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow retryLaterFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(retryLaterChannel())
                           .wireTap(tapChannel())
//                           .bridge(null)
//                           .handle(String.class, (p, h) -> p)
                           .get();
  }

  @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow tapFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(tapChannel())
                           .handle(m -> System.err.println("tap [" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "] " + m.getPayload() ))
                           .get();
  }
}
```

and here is the ExceptionThrowingTransformer:

```
public class ExceptionThrowingTransformer implements GenericTransformer<String, String> {
  @Override
  public String transform(final String source) {
    printAndThrow();
    return Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + source;
  }

  private void printAndThrow() {
    if(numFail > 0) {
      numFail--;
      final String msg = numFail > 0 ? " will fail " + numFail + " more times"
                                     : "last failure";
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " ExceptionThrowingTransformer " + msg);
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }
  private static int numFail = 2;
}
```

Here is the unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = SimpleConfiguration2.class)
public class DependenciesApplicationTests {
  @Test
  public void t1() {
    System.out.println(gw.echo("MSG1"));
  }

  @Autowired
  private EchoGateway gw;
}
```

and the echo gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultReplyTimeout=600)
public interface EchoGateway {
  @Gateway(requestChannel = "requestChannel")
  String echo(String message);
}
```

Question 1:
If I run the code as is, for input "MSG1" that gets placed on requestChannel, I get the following output:

```
main ExceptionThrowingTransformer will fail 1 more times
tap [main] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException
main ExceptionThrowingTransformer last failure
tap [main] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException
main C: MSG1
```

whereas I would expect to see something like:

```
main ExceptionThrowingTransformer will fail 1 more times
main ExceptionThrowingTransformer last failure
main C: MSG1
```

The retry happens, but still the original exception gets propagated to the errorChannel specified in the initFlow gateway. Is there a way to prevent that?

Question 2:
When numFail is changed to 3, besides output like in question 1, an exception is returned to the caller:

```
org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: failure occurred in error-handling flow; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application:-1.retryLaterChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
```

If only the first comment in retryLaterFlow is uncommented, the exception thrown by the exceptionThrowingTransformer is returned to the caller.
Why is that, given that retryTemplate has setThrowLastExceptionOnExhausted(false)?

Question 3:
If only the second comment in retryLaterFlow is uncommented, the output looks like:

```
main ExceptionThrowingTransformer  will fail 2 more times
tap [main] org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException
org.springframework.integration.transformer.MessageTransformationException: ; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: ; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException
```

Why didn't the retry take effect? (Answer to question 1 may also answer this one)

Answer (score 0):

You have two gateways (initial and mid-flow) and you are advising the mid-flow gateway so it is working as expected.

You should be advising the transformer to get the result you expected.